# How to Create and Save Database Objects for Django Tests in the Same Test Case?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models, django-testing

I'm working on Django tests, and I have a base class for my tests where I define some common variables and methods. I want to use fixtures or a similar approach to create database objects and use their attributes in the test data. However, I encountered an issue where the objects created in the base class are not available in the test class.

Here's my simplified test structure:

test_base.py:

```
class BaseTestCases:
    class BaseEndpointTest(APITestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            super().setUpClass()

            # Create users and set up API clients

        @classmethod
        def tearDownClass(cls):
            # Delete users
            super().tearDownClass()

        # Other methods...

        def create(self, data, main_user=True):
            # Create API request
            # ...

# Other code in test_base.py
```

test_cities.py:

```
class TestCities(BaseTestCases.BaseEndpointTest):
    endpoint = "cities"

    # Create a city object using create_city()
    p_key = create_country().pk
    print(Country.objects.all())

    # Test data
    data = {"name": random_string(), "country": p_key}
```

The problem is that when I print Country.objects.all() in test_cities.py, it contains the result of create_city(), but when I print the same in test_base.py using the create method, it doesn't contain the newly created record. I believe this is because the objects created in the base class are not being saved to the test database.

How can I create and save objects in the test database so that they are accessible both in the base class and the test class? Is there a way to make my create_country function work as intended and save objects to the test database?